# Filling GridView with list from databse c# using linq

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql

I am Creating a WCF service and in that I have created a method to fetch one column values from database. Method is

```
   public List<String> AllFriends(string username)
    {

        MyDatabaseEntities acontext = new MyDatabaseEntities();
        var result = from c in acontext.Friends
                     where c.Owner==username
                     select c.Friend1;
        return result.ToList();
    }
```

I am calling this method on client side as:

```
        List<string> friends = new List<string>();
        friends = aSave.AllFriends(Session.username).ToList();
        dataGridView2.DataSource = friends;
```

Problem is when I run this its not filling grid with values but its showing me lenght of values like

```
length
 2
 4
```

when I am calling same method on listbox or combo box then its working fine and showing me proper strings but on grid showing length of strings.
Please help me to fix this.

Comment: I think it's winforms...

Answer (score 0):

That's because grid showing values of public properties of an object.
So you need an object with the string property instead of string itself.. 
It could be anonymous object for example:

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = friends.Select(f => new {Friend = f});
```